# What's the best way to pass markdown to an Astro component as a prop

Tags: javascript, html, markdown, astrojs

#### What I'm trying to do

A simple way to render the content of a markdown file when it's passed as a string to another component using .compiledContent (or even using .rawContnent)? Or even a better way than this as obviously usually in Astro we can use the [<Content /> Component](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/markdown-content/#the-content-component), but from my knowledge, I can't pass a component or this functionality to another component without using a <slot /> in the parent component.

I have some JS for the parent component and using a <slot/> instead of passing the props to the component would change things, so hopefully looking for a solution with using this.

#### My setup

- Data stored in `/src/data/experience` as markdown files with a year and a description formatted as markdown in the content section of each file
- A component called `Tabs.astro` which takes props of headings and contents which are both lists of strings
- A page `/src/pages/experience.astro` with the Tabs component in it which is displaying this data

I take the below code to get the data from the markdown files and pass the years and descriptions to the Tab component.

##### `experience.astro`

```
---
import Tabs from "../components/Tabs.astro";

const jobs = await Astro.glob("../data/experience/*.md");
const years = jobs.map((job) => job.frontmatter.year);
const descriptions = jobs.map((job) => job.compiledContent);
---
<!-- My component taking the data to be rendered -->
<Tabs headings={years} contents={descriptions} />
```

##### `Tabs.astro`

And the component renders the info like so

```
<!-- Tabs -->
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="tabs-header">
    {
      headings.map((heading) => (
        <li>{heading}</li>
      ))
    }
  </ul>
  <ul class="tabs-content">
    {contents.map((content) => <li class="tab">{content}</li>)}
  </ul>
</div>
```

#### My current solution

At the moment using `.compiledContent` gets me the correct HTML, however it is all in a string so the HTML doesn't actually render.

#### What I'm looking for

- Is there a **native way in Astro to pass markdown as a prop to a component**?
- If not is there a manual and **recommended way in Astro to convert a markdown string and sanitise it** to protect against XSS attacks? (if this is a risk in Astro when rendered statically?)
- If not what are your most recommended ways to render markdown and sanitise it in JS?

#### Thanks so much for your time and help! I'm loving using Astro

p.s Also happy to concede and just use a <slot/> in my component if needed... ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Astro has a [`set:html`](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#sethtml) directive you can use in combination with a Fragment like this

```
<Fragment set:html={post.compiledContent()}/>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the input, I have tested this and it does work - but are you aware if I need to santise the content to protect against XSS with this method? Thanks :)

Comment: I replied to your [discord](https://astro.build/chat) thread since its easier to communicate there, but in this case no. The only time you have to sanitize is if its data created by user input like this comment

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of struggling with this myself, the current solution from the Astro docs for a single file without looping is the following.
Import your file with `{Content as YourAliasName} from '../yourPath/yourFileName.md'`
Then just use it as a tag `<YourAliasName />`

Example from the docs for reference:

```
---
import {Content as PromoBanner} from '../components/promoBanner.md';
---

<PromoBanner />
```

https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/markdown-content/#the-content-component

Comment: This is a nice option, but will render the content in its layout, rather than just giving you the content. Not so great if you're building a page.

Answer (score 0):

## Markdown passed as a json structure prop

Please note that this is a little stretch from the original request, but I believe fulfill it in exactly the intended way.

### What is Markdown AST ?

Makrdown [remark](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark) is the conventional way to extract an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) from Markdown which is compatible with standard flavors e.g. Github Flavored Markdown

```js
const processor = remark()
        .use(remarkDirective)
        .use(remarkGfm)
    const markdownAST = processor.parse(content);
```

### How to render an AST with Astro

This is a tricky one but not that complex. In Astro there is possibility to implement a recursive component by using `Astro.self` https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/api-reference/#astroself.
A recursive renderer looks like this

```js
const {node, data} = Astro.props;
const handled_types = [ "root","heading","table","paragraph",
                        "image","code","link","list", "listItem"
                    ]
const other_type = !handled_types.includes(node.type)
---
{(node.type == "root") &&
    <>
        {node.children.map((node)=>(
            <Astro.self node={node} data={data} />
        ))}
    </>
}
{(node.type == "paragraph") &&
<div class="paragraph">
    {node.children.map((node)=>(
        <Astro.self node={node} data={data}/>
    ))}
</div>
}
{(node.type == "list") &&
<ul>
    {node.children.map((node)=>(
        <Astro.self node={node} data={data}/>
    ))}
</ul>
}
{(node.type == "listItem") &&
<li>
    {node.children.map((node)=>(
        <Astro.self node={node} data={data}/>
    ))}
</li>
}
{(node.type == "heading") &&
    <Heading node={node} headings={data.headings}/>
}
{(node.type == "table") &&
    <DataTable node={node} />
}
{(node.type == "image") &&
    <MarkdownImage node={node}  filepath={data.path}/>
}
{(node.type == "code") &&
    <Code node={node}  filepath={data.path}/>
}
{(node.type == "link") &&
    <Link node={node}  filepath={data.path}/>
}
{other_type &&
    <Fragment set:html={toHtml(toHast(node))}></Fragment>
}
```

see also a similar question "How to customize markdown with Astro components?" https://stackoverflow.com/a/77335822/1324481 where I first solved this rendering issue.

## References

I did create a readily implemented solution of the above theory, it is also split in two parts, the first is independent from Astro and turns Markdown into a content management system database, the second render it like you would render data from any headless CMS.

- Markdown to AST and content list https://github.com/MicroWebStacks/content-structure
- example rendering Markdown AST with Astro components where Markdown is passed as json tree prop https://github.com/MicroWebStacks/astro-markdown-render